# C++/Lua FFI to render userdata as a table?

Tags: c++, lua

I have the following simple code in C++ where Object is a std container:

```
static int create_an_object(lua_State* L) {
  auto obj = static_cast<Object*>(lua_newuserdata(L, sizeof(Object*)));
  *obj = another_valid_obj;

  luaL_newmetatable(L, "object_metatable");
  lua_pushcfunction(L, object_metatable_function);
  lua_setfield(L, -2, "__index");
  lua_pop(L, 1);
  return 1;
}

static int object_metatable_function(lua_State* L) {
  string index = luaL_checkstring(L, -1);
  if (index == "foo") {
    lua_pushnumber(L, 123);
  }
  // Handles other indices, or throws error.
}

lua_pushcfunction(L, create_an_object);
lua_setglobal(L, "create_an_object");
```

With the FFI above, I can achieve indexing of Object in Lua such as:

```
local obj = create_an_object()
print(obj.foo)   -- 123
```

Meanwhile `print(obj)` shows that obj is `userdata: 0x12345678`.

Is it possible to use some metamethod magic so that 
`obj` could be used as a table, while `print(obj.foo)` still prints 123? I am running my code in Lua 5.1.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you mean by "could be used as a table", but if you want to print something different from the default from `print(obj)`, then you'll need to assign [`__tostring` metamethod](https://www.lua.org/pil/13.3.html) and return some string from it. This string may look like `"userdata: 0x12345678 = {foo = 123}"` if you want (or simply `"{foo = 123}"`).

If you mean making it work as a table when assigning a new index to it, then [`__newindex` metamethod](https://www.lua.org/pil/13.4.2.html) should be used.

Comment: I want to support operations include index, ipair/pair iteration and getlen (#) for this userdata.

Comment: You can use `__pairs`/`__ipairs` metamethods (Lua 5.2+) and [`__len` metamethod](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#3.4.6) to achieve this.

Comment: Yeah, I know it's doable in 5.2+ but I can only use is 5.1 :(

Comment: @TangKe `__pairs` isn't a "primitive" metamethod like `__index`, `__add`, … – it's just a convention set by the `pairs` function. So you could wrap or re-define `pairs` to check for that: `function pairs( t )  local iter, st, k = next, t, nil ; local mt = getmetatable( t ) ; if mt and mt.__pairs then  iter, st, k = mt.__pairs( t )  end ; return iter, st, k  end` should work very much like 5.3 `pairs`/`__pairs`, I think.